# Replicate Spark Row N-times

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to duplicate a Row in a DataFrame, how can I do that?

For example, I have a DataFrame consisting of 1 Row, and I want to make a DataFrame with 100 identical Rows. I came up with the following solution:

```
  var data:DataFrame=singleRowDF

   for(i<-1 to 100-1) {
       data = data.unionAll(singleRowDF)
   }
```

But this introduces many transformations and it seems my subsequent actions become very slow. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: I don't see why this question should be closed as duplicate because this question is older than the other question... if at all, the other question should be marked as duplicate

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can add a column with a literal value of an Array with size 100, and then use `explode` to make each of its elements create its own row; Then, just get rid of this "dummy" column:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val result = singleRowDF
  .withColumn("dummy", explode(array((1 until 100).map(lit): _*)))
  .selectExpr(singleRowDF.columns: _*)
```

Comment: you could `drop('dummy)` instead of the more complicated `selectExpr`

Comment: @TzachZohar Thats great, although I've still problems to understand how it works :)

Comment: How to rewrite this in pyspark? I tried `df.withColumn("dummy", explode(map(lit, range(repeated)))).drop("dummy")`, and it prints out `literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create ...` error

Comment: in PySpark: `df.withColumn("dummy", F.explode(F.array([F.lit(i) for i in range(100)])))`

Answer (score 1):

You could pick out the single row, make a list with a hundred elements, populated with that row and convert it back into a dataframe.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

val testDf = sc.parallelize(Seq(
    (1,2,3), (4,5,6)
)).toDF("one", "two", "three")

def replicateDf(n: Int, df: DataFrame) = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    sc.parallelize(List.fill(n)(df.take(1)(0)).toSeq), 
    df.schema)

val replicatedDf = replicateDf(100, testDf)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `flatMap`, or a for-comprehension, like it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43551370/how-to-split-multi-value-column-into-separate-rows-using-typed-dataset).

I encourage you to use DataSets every time you can, but if it's not possible, the last example in the link works with DataFrames as well:

```
val df = Seq(
  (0, "Lorem ipsum dolor", 1.0, List("prp1", "prp2", "prp3"))
).toDF("id", "text", "value", "properties")

val df2 = for {
  row <- df
  p <- row.getAs[Seq[String]]("properties")
} yield (row.getAs[Int]("id"), row.getAs[String]("text"), row.getAs[Double]("value"), p)
```

Also keep in mind that `explode` is deprecated, see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@explode[A,B](inputColumn:String,outputColumn:String)(f:A=%3ETraversableOnce[B])(implicitevidence$5:reflect/runtime/universe/TypeTag[B]):org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html).