# Replicating rows in Spark dataframe according values in a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I would like to replicate rows according to their value for a given column. For example, I got this DataFrame:

```
+-----+
|count|
+-----+
|    3|
|    1|
|    4|
+-----+
```

I would like to get:

```
+-----+
|count|
+-----+
|    3|
|    3|
|    3|
|    1|
|    4|
|    4|
|    4|
|    4|
+-----+
```

I tried to use `withColumn` method, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397740/replicate-spark-row-n-times).

```
val replicateDf = originalDf
    .withColumn("replicating", explode(array((1 until $"count").map(lit): _*)))
    .select("count")
```

But `$"count"` is a `ColumnName` and cannot be used to represent its values in the above expression.

(I also tried with `explode(Array.fill($"count"){1})` but same problem here.)

What do I need to change? Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: What about using flatMap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_repeat` is available from 2.4 onwards. If you need the solution in lower versions, you can use udf() or rdd. For Rdd, check this out

```
import scala.collection.mutable._

val df = Seq(3,1,4).toDF("count")
val rdd1 = df.rdd.flatMap( x=> { val y = x.getAs[Int]("count"); for ( p <- 0 until y ) yield Row(y) }  )
spark.createDataFrame(rdd1,df.schema).show(false)
```

Results:

```
+-----+
|count|
+-----+
|3    |
|3    |
|3    |
|1    |
|4    |
|4    |
|4    |
|4    |
+-----+
```

With df() alone

```
scala> df.flatMap( r=> { (0 until r.getInt(0)).map( i => r.getInt(0)) } ).show
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    3|
|    3|
|    3|
|    1|
|    4|
|    4|
|    4|
|    4|
+-----+
```

For udf(), below would work

```
val df = Seq(3,1,4).toDF("count")
def array_repeat(x:Int):Array[Int]={
  val y = for ( p <- 0 until x )yield x
  y.toArray
}
val udf_array_repeat = udf (array_repeat(_:Int):Array[Int] )
df.withColumn("count2", explode(udf_array_repeat('count))).select("count2").show(false)
```

**EDIT :**

Check @user10465355's answer below for more information about `array_repeat`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_repeat`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@array_repeat(left:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,right:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array_repeat, explode}

val df = Seq(1, 2, 3).toDF

df.select(explode(array_repeat($"value", $"value"))).show()
```

```
+---+
|col|
+---+
|  1|
|  2|
|  2|
|  3|
|  3|
|  3|
+---+
```

Comment: This seems to work only if the number of repetitions is int, but not bigint..